# indices[201] = [0,8] is out of order. Many sparse ops require sorted indices.Use `tf.sparse.reorder` to create a correctly ordered copy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, sparse-matrix

Im doing a neural network encoding every variable and when im going to fit the model, an error raises.

```
indices[201] = [0,8] is out of order. Many sparse ops require sorted indices.
    Use `tf.sparse.reorder` to create a correctly ordered copy.

 [Op:SerializeManySparse]
```

I dunno how to solve it. 
I can print some code here and if u want more i can still printing it

```
def process_atributes(df, train, test):

    continuas = ['Trip_Duration']
    cs = MinMaxScaler()
    trainCont = cs.fit_transform(train[continuas])
    testCont = cs.transform(test[continuas])

    discretas = ['Start_Station_Name', 'End_Station_Name', 'User_Type', 'Genero', 'Hora_inicio']
    ohe = OneHotEncoder()
    ohe.fit(train[discretas])

    trainDisc = ohe.transform(train[discretas])
    testDisc = ohe.transform(test[discretas])

    trainX = sc.sparse.hstack((trainDisc, trainCont))
    testX = sc.sparse.hstack((testDisc, testCont))
    return (trainX, testX)

def prepare_targets(df, train, test):

    labeled_col = ['RangoEdad']

    le = LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(train[labeled_col].values.ravel())
    trainY = le.transform(train[labeled_col])
    testY = le.transform(test[labeled_col])
    return trainY, testY

X_train_enc, X_test_enc = process_atributes(dataFrameDepurado2, train, test)
Y_train_enc, Y_test_enc = prepare_targets(dataSetPrueba, train, test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim = X_train_enc.shape[1], activation = 'tanh', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = SGD(lr = 0.01), metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train_enc, Y_train_enc, validation_data = (X_test_enc, Y_test_enc), epochs = 20, batch_size = 64, shuffle = True)
```

This is my DataSet

[image: this is my dataSet]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If your sparse array is encoded as row `1` column `[4, 2, 1, 5, 9]` data `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` the column index is out of order. `Use 'tf.sparse.reorder' to create a correctly ordered copy.`

Comment: Where should i use this function? Because the input of this function is a Sparse Tensor, not a Sparse Matrix.
Do you want more code to solve this problem?
Thank you anyway

Comment: You should use it prior to fitting your model. If you'd prefer, you can use `.sort_indices()` on a scipy sparse matrix to sort the indices before you turn it into a tensor.

Answer (score 7):

Mentioning the solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in the Comments Section, for the **benefit of the Community**.

The documentation for [SparseTensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/SparseTensor) states

```
By convention, indices should be sorted in row-major order (or equivalently 
lexicographic order on the tuples indices[i]). This is not enforced when
SparseTensor objects are constructed, but most ops assume correct ordering. If 
the ordering of sparse tensor st is wrong, a fixed version can be obtained by
calling [tf.sparse.reorder(st)][2].
```

So, using either `tf.sparse.reorder` or `scipy.sort_indices` on the matrices, `X_train_enc, X_test_enc, Y_train_enc, Y_test_enc`, before the line of code,

```
model.fit(X_train_enc, Y_train_enc, validation_data = (X_test_enc, 
Y_test_enc), epochs = 20, batch_size = 64, shuffle = True)
```

will resolve the issue.

For more information, please refer documentation of [Sparse Tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/SparseTensor) and [tf.sparse.reorder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/reorder).

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!