# Tensorflow sparse ops require sorted indices

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to fine tuning Bert for document classification.

I started by tokenizing the documents to generate the `input_ids`, `attention_mask` and `token_type_ids` lists to feed my TFBertModel:

```
def tokenize_sequences(tokenizer, max_length, corpus):
    input_ids = []
    token_type_ids = []
    attention_masks = []

    for i in tqdm(range(len(corpus))):
      encoded = tokenizer.encode_plus(
          corpus[i], 
          max_length=max_length, 
          add_special_tokens=True,
          padding='max_length',
          truncation=True,
          return_token_type_ids=True,
          return_attention_mask=True,  # add attention mask to not focus on pad tokens)
      )
      input_ids.append(encoded["input_ids"])
      attention_masks.append(encoded["attention_mask"])
      token_type_ids.append(encoded["token_type_ids"])

    input_ids = tf.convert_to_tensor(input_ids)
    attention_masks = tf.convert_to_tensor(attention_masks)
    token_type_ids = tf.convert_to_tensor(token_type_ids)
    #print(input_ids.shape, attention_masks.shape, token_type_ids.shape)

    return [input_ids, attention_masks, token_type_ids]
```

Then, I tried to fit my model:

```
x_train = tokenize_sequences(tokenizer, MAXLEN, corpus_train)
model = loadBertModel()

model.fit(
    x_train, y_bin_train,
    epochs=N_EPOCHS,
    verbose=1,
    batch_size=4, 
  )
```

And I get this error:

> InvalidArgumentError: indices[3] = [1,5] is out of order. Many sparse ops require sorted indices.
> Use `tf.sparse.reorder` to create a correctly ordered copy.

I tried to solve the issue following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61961042/indices201-0-8-is-out-of-order-many-sparse-ops-require-sorted-indices-use) suggestion. I did this by modifying `input_ids, attention_masks, token_type_ids` tensors returned by `tokenize_sequences`.

```
input_ids = tf.sparse.reorder(input_ids)
attention_masks = tf.sparse.reorder(attention_masks)
token_type_ids = tf.sparse.reorder(token_type_ids)
```

But then another error occurred:

> TypeError: Input must be a SparseTensor.

PS: When I checked the type of my tensors, I noticed that they were `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>`.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment, so I'm trying to comment by answering..
It seems this question is same as yours:

[Multiclass text classification TypeError: Input must be a SparseTensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67342655/multiclass-text-classification-typeerror-input-must-be-a-sparsetensor)

In my case, I solved a similar issue by simply converting the inputs using .toarray() instead of trying to reorder them.

```
input_ids = input_ids.toarray()
```